# How to remove duplicate value from nested list?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my list:

```
lists=[[2], [3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8], [9], [9, 10, 11], [10]]
```

I would like to remove values that duplicated with other elements.

Among the list, **[9]** and **[10]** are in **[9, 10, 11]**

I want **[9, 10, 11]** to be remained, but remove single **[9]** and **[10]**

Could anyone tell me how could I do that?

I hope the list could be:

```
lists=[[2], [3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: What would you do about something like `[[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]`?

Comment: how many levels of nesting are we talking about?

Comment: in your example you find 9 in `[9]` and in `[9,10,11]` , the same with 10. So do you want the list with longer length to be retained?

Comment: @RyanZhang There would possibly be [[2],[2,3],[4],[4,5]]. Only a single element would be duplicated with one in other list of element.

Comment: @RinkeshP Yes. That's what i hope for.

Comment: @ankerbow. I see. So in the list of lists, there are single element lists. And you want to remove these if a longer list includes it.

Comment: @RyanZhang Yes.

Comment: @ankerbow Great. I'll see how I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach.

1. We'll use a set (call this `a`) to store all the elements that appear in lists length longer than 1.
2. We'll go through the single element lists. If it appears in the set, we shouldn't add it. Otherwise, add it.

Below is an implementation (which should hopefully be easy to understand and read, as well as being thoroughly commented):

```
lists = [[2], [3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8], [9], [9, 10, 11], [10]]
ans = []
a = set() 
for i in lists:
    if len(i) > 1: #if this is a list with more than 1 element
        for j in i: #go through its elements
            a.add(j) #put it in the set, so we know what to ignore later

for i in lists:
    if len(i) > 1:
        ans.append(i) #if there's more than 1 element, we should add it to the final answer
    else:
        if i[0] not in a:
            ans.append(i) #append if it does not appear in the set

lists = ans #copy the answer list to the original (optional step)
print(lists)
```

This gives the desired output:

```
[[2], [3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

---

Of course, if you don't care about readability, you could use the one-liner:

```
lists = list(filter(lambda i: len(i) > 1 or not (any(i[0] in sb for sb in list(filter(lambda i: len(i) > 1, lists)))), lists))
```

This gives the same correct output.